# Why do uint8_t arrays behave different to uint16_t array when using begin() and end()?

Tags: c++11

I am trying to understand why the following code snippet behaves different for the `uint16_t` array than the `uint8_t` array.
I would expect memory addresses to be printed for both cases. What am I missing?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    uint16_t a[3] = { 65, 66, 67 };
    uint8_t b[3] = { 88, 89, 90 };
    
    std::cout << std::begin(a) << " " << std::end(a) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::begin(b) << " " << std::end(b) << std::endl;
}
```

Sample output:

```
0x7ffee64ca990 0x7ffee64ca996
XYZ
```

Comment: It is the `<<` operator on ostream that has special behaviour for pointer to character types . You could do `static_cast<void *>(std::begin(b))` for example

Comment: Why is there no space in the second line of the output?

Comment: @mkrieger1 there actually is, its just hard to spot. If you highlight the text using your mouse you can see it.

Comment: @M.M thank you! That explains all my confusion!

Comment: @M.M Either you should post an answer or the question should be closed as a duplicate. (It probably is one, but I'm too lazy to go hunting.)

Comment: @KeithThompson duplicate is probably the way to go, this comes up frequently

Comment: @M472 the behaviour is undefined since there is no null terminator in the input , so we could see anything really